# zip command globbing folder while zipping with sudo

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run a zip command as user1:

```
[user1@host ~]$ sudo zip -P 68SqkCtNAxUpVoX8KPm /tmp/metazip /mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/sl_keystore/* /home/user2/sqllib/sqlrsdir/* /home/user2/sqllib/profile.env /home/user2/sqllib/db2systm /home/user2/db2/keystore/*
        zip warning: name not matched: /home/user2/db2/keystore/*        
updating: mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/bludb_ssl.crl (stored 0%)
updating: mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/bludb_ssl.kdb (deflated 69%)
updating: mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/bludb_ssl.rdb (deflated 1%)
updating: mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/bludb_ssl.sth (stored 0%)
updating: home/user2/sqllib/sqlrsdir/sqlrsbak (deflated 94%)
updating: home/user2/sqllib/sqlrsdir/sqlrsdir (deflated 94%)
updating: home/user2/sqllib/profile.env (deflated 34%)
updating: home/user2/sqllib/db2systm (deflated 98%)
```

As you can see `/home/user2/db2/keystore/` is not being zipped because user1 does not have permissions to access that folder

```
[user1@host ~]$ ls -l /home/user2/db2/keystore/
ls: cannot open directory /home/user2/db2/keystore/: Permission denied
```

current permissions on /home/user2/db2/keystore is:

```
[root@host /]# ls -l /home/user2/db2/keystore/
total 12
-rw------- 1 user2 db2iadm1 6846 Oct 21 17:30 keystore.p12
-rw------- 1 user2 db2iadm1  193 Oct 21 15:11 keystore.sth
[root@host /]# ls -l /home/user2/db2/
total 4
drwx------ 2 user2 db2iadm1 6144 Oct 21 15:11 keystore
```

If I change the permissions of these files and folders to

```
[root@host /]# ls -l /home/user2/db2/keystore/
total 12
-rw-r----- 1 user2 db2iadm1 6846 Oct 21 17:30 keystore.p12
-rw-r----- 1 user2 db2iadm1  193 Oct 21 15:11 keystore.sth
[root@host /]# ls -l /home/user2/db2/
total 4
drwxr----- 2 user2 db2iadm1 6144 Oct 21 15:11 keystore
```

I am able to zip. But sudo (root) has permissions to access the files and folders so zip with sudo should have been able to zip these. Assuming globing I tried `\` to skip `*` and also `''` to overcome the issue but still unable to zip that folder. Any clue what is missing here?

Comment: When you run `zip foo /path/*.whatever`, the `*.whatever` globbing operation is done *by the shell*, before `zip` even starts. `sudo zip` escalates zip's privileges, but the globbing is already finished before that escalation happens (indeed, before `sudo` is executed at all).

Comment: BTW, this is probably a better fit for [unix.se]; Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about tools and practices "unique to software development".

Comment: (The context of manual-vs-scripted operation is extra important for purposes of evaluating which potential answers are acceptable from a security perspective -- the easy answers can be dangerous if you're using a password provided by a user who doesn't themselves have root privileges).

Comment: (BTW, another note with my security hat on -- using a hardcoded filename in `/tmp` is generally a bad idea for a security-sensitive operation; consider the case where someone creates a symlink from `/tmp/metazip` to a pre-created file they have permissions to read named `/home/evilguy/metazip` before your script is run).

Answer (score 0):

Globbing is performed by the shell, not by zip, so escalating zip's privileges doesn't change whether the glob operation takes place. Use `sudo` to run a new/different shell with enough privileges to do the glob:

```
sudo sh -s <<'EOF'
zip -P 68SqkCtNAxUpVoX8KPm /tmp/metazip /mnt/blumeta0/db2/ssl_keystore/sl_keystore/* /home/user2/sqllib/sqlrsdir/* /home/user2/sqllib/profile.env /home/user2/sqllib/db2systm /home/user2/db2/keystore/*
EOF
```

Comment: If I put this in a shell script it gives syntax error.

Comment: I'd need to see the context of *how* it's added to a script, and exactly what that error is. And, of course, exactly which shell is in use. Nothing about the code given is itself invalid syntax, but it could *become* invalid syntax if, say, you did something like indenting the `EOF` (heredoc sigils only work if on their own line with no indentation; there's an alternate syntax that allows *some* indentation, but even that only works with tabs and not spaces).

Comment: ok I got the syntax issue fixed but the problem with this is the variables before this piece all get lost and seems like the code after this piece get executed in some different shell.

Comment: That's right; executing them in a different shell is the *point*, because your initial shell doesn't have enough permissions.

Comment: Anyhow, your question doesn't *show* any variables being used, so I don't answer the question (about how to use them) that wasn't asked. If you want to know how to pass variables through to a new shell started by sudo, ask a new question if you can't find an existing one on the topic. (There's the *dangerously wrong* way of just changing from `<<'EOF'` to `<<EOF`, but that introduces serious security problems; don't accept any answer that suggests it).